# Error en setOnContextClickListener Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Buenas noches amigos tengo un formulario de un carrito de compras y voy seleccionando los productos pero es que tengo bebidas y comidas, hasta ahi todo me funciona y veo que se va incrementando las cantidades de productos seleccionados. el problema esta cuando quiero ver la lista de lo seleccionado tengo un un boton "Ver carrito de compras" tengo 2 apdatadores uno para los productos y otros para las bebidas y me funciona bien pero en ambos tengo el setOnContextClickListener  del boton "ver carrito de compras".
pero cuando le doy click al boton del carrito este no se dispara ni se muestra trato de buggear pero nada no llega ahi. NO SE QUE HACER ... GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO.

Este el codigo del adaptador de las bebidas:

```
public class AdaptadorBebidas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorBebidas.BebidasViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    TextView tvCantProductos;
    Button btnVerCarro;
    List<Producto> listaBebidas;
    List<Producto> carroCompra;

    public AdaptadorBebidas(Context context, TextView tvCantProductos, Button btnVerCarro, List<Producto> listaBebidas, List<Producto> carroCompra) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tvCantProductos = tvCantProductos;
        this.btnVerCarro = btnVerCarro;
        this.listaBebidas = listaBebidas;
        this.carroCompra = carroCompra;
    }

    public BebidasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_productos, null, false);
        return new AdaptadorBebidas.BebidasViewHolder(v);
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final BebidasViewHolder bebidasViewHolder, final int i) {
        bebidasViewHolder.tvNomProducto.setText(listaBebidas.get(i).getNomProducto());
        bebidasViewHolder.tvDescripcion.setText(listaBebidas.get(i).getDescripcion());
        bebidasViewHolder.tvPrecio.setText(""+listaBebidas.get(i).getPrecio());
        bebidasViewHolder.cbCarro.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (bebidasViewHolder.cbCarro.isChecked() == true) {
                    tvCantProductos.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(tvCantProductos.getText().toString().trim()) + 1));
                    carroCompra.add(listaBebidas.get(i));
                } else if (bebidasViewHolder.cbCarro.isChecked() == false) {
                    tvCantProductos.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(tvCantProductos.getText().toString().trim()) - 1));
                    carroCompra.remove(listaBebidas.get(i));
                }
            }
        });

        btnVerCarro.setOnContextClickListener(new View.OnContextClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onContextClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CarroCompra.class);
                intent.putExtra("CarroCompras", (Serializable) carroCompra);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaBebidas.size();
    };

    public class BebidasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvNomProducto, tvDescripcion, tvPrecio;
        CheckBox cbCarro;

        public BebidasViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvNomProducto =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomProducto);
            tvDescripcion=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
            tvPrecio=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
            cbCarro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbCarro);
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo del otro adaptador el de Productos. es lo mismo solo cambia las variables ya que ambos son diferentes reciclyvewer.

```
Public class AdaptadorProductos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorProductos.ProductosViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    TextView tvCantProductos;
    Button btnVerCarro;
    List<Producto> listaProductos;
    List<Producto> carroCompra;

    public AdaptadorProductos(Context context, TextView tvCantProductos, Button btnVerCarro, List<Producto> listaProductos, List<Producto> carroCompra) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tvCantProductos = tvCantProductos;
        this.btnVerCarro = btnVerCarro;
        this.listaProductos = listaProductos;
        this.carroCompra = carroCompra;
    }

    public ProductosViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
           View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_productos, null, false);
           return new AdaptadorProductos.ProductosViewHolder(v);
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductosViewHolder productosViewHolder, final int i) {
        productosViewHolder.tvNomProducto.setText(listaProductos.get(i).getNomProducto());
        productosViewHolder.tvDescripcion.setText(listaProductos.get(i).getDescripcion());
        productosViewHolder.tvPrecio.setText(""+listaProductos.get(i).getPrecio());
        productosViewHolder.cbCarro.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (productosViewHolder.cbCarro.isChecked() == true) {
                   tvCantProductos.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(tvCantProductos.getText().toString().trim()) + 1));
                   carroCompra.add(listaProductos.get(i));
                } else if (productosViewHolder.cbCarro.isChecked() == false) {
                    tvCantProductos.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(tvCantProductos.getText().toString().trim()) - 1));
                    carroCompra.remove(listaProductos.get(i));
                }
            }
        });

        btnVerCarro.setOnContextClickListener(new View.OnContextClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onContextClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CarroCompra.class);
                intent.putExtra("CarroCompras", (Serializable) carroCompra);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return listaProductos.size();
    };

    public class ProductosViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvNomProducto, tvDescripcion, tvPrecio;
        CheckBox cbCarro;

        public ProductosViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvNomProducto =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomProducto);
            tvDescripcion=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
            tvPrecio=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
            cbCarro = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbCarro);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué estás usando ContextClickListener en vez de ClickListener? Hasta donde sé, el context es cuando pulsas con el botón derecho de un ratón. Otra cosa. Si el botón no tiene nada que ver con el Adapter, ¿porqué metes el listener en la clase del adapter. Puedes incluir una función en el Adapter que te retorne la lista de elementos y desde la Activity o Fragment donde esté el botón, cuando se lance el listener, le pides la Lista al Adapter y lanzas la nueva Activity. Si el botón del carro no está en el recyclerView, qué sentido tiene que lo metas en el adapter del recycler?

Comment: Hola amigo SuperG280 me podrias regalar un ejemplo gracias

Comment: Gracias SuperG280 puede solucionar el error gracias por tu comentario me guió mucho y pude sacarlo adelante. Bendiciones amigo.       final Button btn_pedido = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVerCarro);
       btn_pedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v){
               Intent i = new Intent(Pedidos.this, CarroCompra.class);
               i.putExtra("CarroCompras", (Serializable) carroCompra);
               startActivity(i);
           }
       });